# How to read words in a text file in python

Tags: python, file

## I have this text file :

```
banana, yellow
apple, red
carrot, orange
```

---

### and I need the program to read it and send the output as:

---

```
banana = yellow
apple = red
carrot = orange
```

---

how am I supposed to do this in python?, 
By the way its python3.8, kind of obvious

Comment: loop through the file and uses `str.replace` function

Comment: may we know what have you tried. kind of obvious that it is hard to figure out what problem(s) that you have encounter if you do not show your code. it is kind of obvious too that people do not write code for you, thanks.

Comment: @D.Seah : yeah well actually i didn't had anything else written as I just needed to know how to do this to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
with open('text.txt','r') as f: # Opens the file with the read format
    print(f.read().replace(', ',' = ')) # Prints out the contents, with each ', ' replaced with ' = '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r') 
Lines = file1.readlines() 

for line in Lines: 
    print(line.replace(",","="))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("file.txt","r")
for i in f:
     s,s1 = i.split(',')
     print(s+" = "+s1)
f.close()
```

Explanation:

1. Firstly open the file in read mode indicated by "r"
2. loop through all lines in file
3. words are separated  using split(','),Which will store first word in
   s and second in s1
4. print it
5. close the file